# Spring Boot: Extend/Edit Apache HttpClientBuilder with different configurations?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am having an architectural issue with the Apache HttpComponents HttpClient.

We have a system where we have several different remote endpoints that we want to contact, and each have some different configurations like ssl, basic auth, et cetera.

I am using Spring Boot and Cloud Sleuth from which I get a `HttpClientBuilder` that gives me tracing and other things. I want to re-use **that** `HttpClientBuilder` but on-top of that **add** my own specific configurations, for each unique endpoint.

The problem though is that the `HttpCientBuilder` is not immutable with `withXYZ()` methods, nor is there a `copy` or `clone` method on the builder, so I can't copy the original and change just my specific changes there without altering the base `HttpClientBuilder` and get into conflicts with others that use the same instance of the builder. Be it racing conditions between threads or conflicting configurations between the different endpoints.

One place in the Spring Boot project where I have seen them seemingly wanting to do something similar is in `HttpClientConfiguration` of `Spring Cloud Commons` where it creates an own `ApacheHttpClientFactory` which takes the original autowired `HttpClientBuilder` and then sets `disableContentCompression()`, `disableCookieManagement()` and `useSystemProperties()` -- but it seemingly does it to the original instance of the `HttpClientBuilder` which just seems completely wrong to me. It will alter how all the built `HttpClient` works, and not just the one they will later be using in their Ribbon code in `HttpClientRibbonConfiguration` of `Spring Cloud Netflix Ribbon`. A potential bug in hiding? To me it seems like it, since it highly depends on calling order.

Does anyone have any ideas how something like this should be solved?

The easy alternative that I could do is to just not try and build upon the given `HttpClientBuilder` from Sleuth, but instead build a completely new one from the ground-up every time I need one, and check if a `HttpTracing` bean is available and use `TracingHttpCientBuilder` instead of `HttpClientBuilder` in that case, but this seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: Why would you want a different instance of HttpClient for different endpoints? This does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: @ok2c It doesn't? But they have different ssl contexts, BASIC authentication, et cetera. Is it not recommended to set these settings on the HttpClientBuilder rather than trying to manipulate on the HttpClient directly for every request?

Comment: That is what `HttpContext` is for.

Comment: @ok2c Could you please explain how `HttpContext` solves asked question? `HttpContext` can be of course used and configured for each request and you can always do some custom interceptor to handle given configuration. It does the job, but it is not friendly when you need shared configuration for multiple endpoints. Image that you have application communicating with 20 other systems and each system uses different auth protocol and you can expect different timeout settings for them. This is reason why it would be nice to have immutable HTTP client builder to do configuration per each system.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem. However, I had the option of defining my own `HttpClientBuilder` bean. I am not sure you are in the same position?

But by making the bean scope "prototype" a new bean instance is created every time it is injected somewhere. Then I could safely modify the HttpClientBuilder after injection.

```
    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public HttpClientBuilder tracingHttpClientBuilder(..) {
    ...
    }
```